# DeviceIoControl (IOCTL_NDISUIO_OPEN_DEVICE) is failed in WINCE7 C#.net

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I am working on WIN CE platform, developing windows forms in C#.Net. Successfully created handle for NDISUIO ("UIO1:").

Check the API:

```
                string AUB_NAME = "PCI\\ManiXX1";

                byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AUB_NAME);              

                int IOCTL_NDIS_QUERY = new int();
                IOCTL_NDIS_QUERY = IOCTL_NDISUIO_OPEN_DEVICE;

                IoctlResult = DeviceIoControl(
                                    hFileHandle,
                                    IOCTL_NDIS_QUERY,
                                    toBytes,
                                    (int)(11 * sizeof(UInt16)),//It should be 11 or 22 bytes?
                                    null,
                                    0,
                                    ref dwReturnedBytes,
                                    0);
```

The above syntax is corresponding to the first prototype as mentioned below.

Prototype for the Above API:

```
//deviceIoControl - overloaded
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool DeviceIoControl(int hDevice, int dwIoControlCode, 
                                              byte[] InBuffer, int nInBufferSize,
                                              byte[] OutBuffer, int nOutputBufferSize, 
                                              ref int pBytesReturned, int pOverlapped);
```

When I run this code in WIN CE machine I am getting the error code 87, (The parameter is incorrect.ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)

I am checking the parameters, I feel those are correct, can anybody tell me regarding the parameters info and its type, which prototype should be followed for deviceiocontrol API in C#.net Compact framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks wrong to me:

```
byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AUB_NAME);
```

Windows CE is very, very heavily biased toward Unicode.  It should probably be:

```
byte[] toBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(AUB_NAME);
```

Comment: Sir.. How to pass the structures/ pointers in deviceIOcontrol API for C#.net @ctacke

Comment: Can you tell me where I am doing wrong for this Query:

[DeviceIoControl (IOCTL_NDISUIO_NIC_STATISTICS) is failed in WINCE7 C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479009/deviceiocontrol-ioctl-ndisuio-nic-statistics-is-failed-in-wince7-c-net)

@ctacke

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party here, but two other things to be aware of with `IOCTL_NDISUIO_OPEN_DEVICE`:

1. The input buffer passed to `DeviceIoControl` must not be `const`, or the call will fail with error 87 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`) as NDISUIO attempts to copy data back into the input buffer(!) So don't pass a string literal the way [some MSDN samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms892535.aspx) do.
2. The length of the input buffer *must not* include the terminating NUL. If it does, NDISUIO will fail to locate the adapter name in its internal list and return error 31 (`ERROR_GEN_FAILURE`). MSDN does point out that [the NULL character should be disregarded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee481644(v=winembedded.60).aspx), but the wording makes it sound optional when in reality it isn't.