# How to send the structure pointer to DeviceIoControl API in WINCE7 C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, windows-ce

I am working on WIN CE platform, developing windows forms in C#.Net.

The DeviceIoControl API is working fine with the parameters (mentioned below) in c++ console application.

> PNIC_STATISTICS structure in nuiouser.h

```
  global declarations :
  TCHAR PCI1_NAME[] = _T("PCI\\ManiXX1"); 
  TCHAR *AUB_NAME = NULL;       
  AUB_NAME = PCI1_NAME; 

   pNICStat = (PNIC_STATISTICS)malloc(sizeof(NIC_STATISTICS)) ;

   pNICStat->ptcDeviceName = AUB_NAME ;           //wchar_t* ptcDeviceName 

   DeviceIoControl( hUB94Port,                         //void*
                 IOCTL_NDISUIO_NIC_STATISTICS,
                 pNICStat,                         //PNIC_STATISTICS 
                 0,
                 pNICStat,                        //PNIC_STATISTICS 
                 sizeof(NIC_STATISTICS),
                 &dwReturnedBytes,
                 NULL
               );
```

<==============================================================================>
But I'm getting problems in implementing the same with C#.Net CF for WIN-CE7

My WIN-CE Code is as follows:

Modified Structure in C#:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct __NIC_STAT
    {

        ulong Size;               //  Of this structure.

        public Char[] ptcDeviceName;      //  The device name to be queried.. 

        ulong DeviceState;        //  DEVICE_STATE_XXX above
        ulong DeviceState;        //  DEVICE_STATE_XXX above
        ulong MediaType;          //  NdisMediumXXX
        ulong MediaState;         //  MEDIA_STATE_XXX above
        ulong PhysicalMediaType;
        ulong LinkSpeed;          //  In 100bits/s. 10Mb/s = 100000
        UInt64 PacketsSent;
        UInt64 PacketsReceived;
        ulong InitTime;           //  In milliseconds
        ulong ConnectTime;        //  In seconds
        UInt64 BytesSent;          //  0 - Unknown (or not supported)
        UInt64 BytesReceived;      //  0 - Unknown (or not supported)
        UInt64 DirectedBytesReceived;
        UInt64 DirectedPacketsReceived;
        ulong PacketsReceiveErrors;
        ulong PacketsSendErrors;
        ulong ResetCount;
        ulong MediaSenseConnectCount;
        ulong MediaSenseDisconnectCount; 

    } ;
```

From this Structure I am just filling ptcDeviceName and trying to send.

```
 __NIC_STAT NIC_STAT = new __NIC_STAT();

  Char[] toBytes = {'P','C','I','\\','M','a','n','i','X','X','1','\0'}

  NIC_STAT.ptcDeviceName = toBytes;        //public Char[] ptcDeviceName; in structure 
                                      // __NIC_STAT this is the same structure as 
                                      //in  nuiouser.h     


    int sz = Marshal.SizeOf(NIC_STAT.GetType());//sometimes Getting exception here

     intptr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sz);

     Marshal.StructureToPtr((__NIC_STAT)NIC_STAT, ptr, false);

   unsafe 
   {           

         DeviceIoControl(hFileHandle,
                     IOCTL_NDISUIO_NIC_STATISTICS,
                     ref ptr,
                     0,
                     ref ptr,
                     sz,
                     ref dwReturnedBytes,
                     0);
  }//unsafe
```

It's corresponding prototype

```
  [DllImport("coredll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
unsafe public static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
                                                  int hDevice, 
                                                  int dwIoControlCode, 
                                                  ref intptr InBuffer,
                                                  int nInBufferSize,
                                                  ref intptr OutBuffer,
                                                  int nOutputBufferSize, 
                                                  ref int pBytesReturned,
                                                  int pOverlapped
                                                 );
```

In Win-CE DeviceIoControl() is getting failed, with exception and not displaying any error codes. and sometimes getting error code as 87 (INVALID PARAMETERS).

I feel ptcDeviceName is creating the problem or may be because of allocating memory for pointer (ptr) ?

In Console application we are sending ptcDeviceName as Wchar_t* but in  WIN-CE so I used

```
public Char[] ptcDeviceName;
```

Can anybody tell me where I am doing wrong.?

Comment: Your C++ comment says you're passing in a wchar_t, but your code disagrees. Which is correct? `pNICStat->ptcDeviceName = "PCI\\Manixx1";` or `L"PCI\\Manixx1";`

Comment: __NIC_STAT is defined in C# it is the same structure as PNIC_STATISTICS structure in nuiouser.h @ctacke

[ctacke](http://stackoverflow.com/users/13154/ctacke)

Comment: `pNICStat->ptcDeviceName = L"PCI\\Manixx1";` is correct way @PaulH

Comment: possible duplicate of [DeviceIoControl (IOCTL\_NDISUIO\_OPEN\_DEVICE) is failed in WINCE7 C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454350/deviceiocontrol-ioctl-ndisuio-open-device-is-failed-in-wince7-c-net)

Comment: @Keshava That was a different Qn.. :(

This Qn is Different with Different approach in sending the information to DeviceIoControl function.

Comment: How can we help you if you withhold vital information. I've asked repeatedly to see the struct, but you won't show it.

Comment: Put on hold as 'unclear' because we don't have all the information we need to solve your issue; also, if this differs from the possible duplicate, could you put those differences in your question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan other part of the code is not much important

The Structure NIC_STATISTICS is available in nuiouser.h 

My problem is sending the structure information to DeviceIoControl API, in similar fashion to C++ code as mentioned.
but C# is not allowing me to convert struct to pointer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker 

in [DeviceIoControl (IOCTL_NDISUIO_OPEN_DEVICE) is failed in WINCE7 C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454350/deviceiocontrol-ioctl-ndisuio-open-device-is-failed-in-wince7-c-net)

we are just sending a string to open NDISUIO Device,

but here I am sending the structure info, My main problem is in  sending the structure information to DeviceIoControl API, in similar fashion to C++ code as mentioned. but C# is not allowing me to convert struct to pointer.

Comment: @arya2arya This information should be in your question. Not in a comment. Comments are hard to parse and follow for future visitors.

Comment: @arya2arya You cannot compile a C header file into your C# program. You must have translated it. You might have done it wrong. I am experienced in answering interop questions. It seems as though you don't want us to help you. I now give up.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker yep Sir.. But I've mentioned in the Qn title itself problem in sending structure information, In the body of the Qn also I posted the code regarding structure conversions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am not compiling the C header file, I have shown you the structure info for reference purpose, 

Yep Sir I know You are well experienced person, I am just a beginner want to learn more.

Comment: You have not shown the structure. Not your C# translation. I won't ask again.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan

Modified Structure in C#:





        `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct __NIC_STAT
        {
           ulong Size;               //  Of this structure.
           public Char[] ptcDeviceName;//  The device name to be queried..
           ulong DeviceState;        //  DEVICE_STATE_XXX above
            ....... //other parameters as in nuiouser.h
        } ;`

Comment: Not in a comment. In the question. And all of it. Do you want help, or not? Also, this question is on hold and will not get an answer. Your other question is still alive.

Comment: @arya2arya You don't get it, do you? `// other parameter as in nuiouser.h` does *not* help. We need to see the *entire* structure. Please copy & paste it into your question. Is is that hard? Why don't you understand that this is information we need to help!?

Comment: Your struct only has three members. That's clearly wrong.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I added the information in the Question.

Comment: This question is on hold now so we cannot answer it. I can see lots of errors in your code and would be able to add a useful answer. Could you put the struct in the other question please?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sure Sir.

I ll add the structure to other Qn.

Comment: @PaulH

Sir I am using 2 byte char

pNICStat->ptcDeviceName = L"PCI\\Manixx1";

Comment: can you verify that `sizeof(NIC_STATISTICS)` in C is the same value as you get for `Marshal.SizeOf(NIC_STAT.GetType());` in c#?

Comment: Just saw your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22506695/57185) answered by @David Heffernan. Does it work now? Are the struct sizes equal? If not, please update this question with the new information.

Comment: @PaulH

Yes that answer is helpful in declaration of the structure. 

Marshal.SizeOf() throwing an exception in WIN CE machine

Comment: @arya2arya You may need to declare the name as `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni`. That would make the structure be blittable. At which point `sizeof` would then be fine too.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, it's a valid question, and I fully understand it.  I also know what the problem is (well there are multiple problems) now that the struct was added to the question, but I can't provide an answer until it gets re-opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple problems going on here.

First is that you seem to think a `ulong` is 32-bits in C#, but it's not.  It'64 bits, so your struct is totally mapped wrong.

Second, I'm sure you need to be setting the struct `Size` member before passing it to the call.

Third, that `ptcDeviceName` member is a pointer to a wide character string.  That means that in the struct itself it's 4 bytes.  I'd likely make it an `IntPtr`.  You then need to separately allocate the string, pin it, and put the pointer to it into that member slot.  Since `StringToHGlobal doesn't exist in the CF, it would look something like this:

```
public struct __NIC_STAT
{
    public uint Size;
    public IntPtr ptcDeviceName;
    public uint DeviceState;
    public uint DeviceState;
    public uint MediaType;
    public uint MediaState;
    public uint PhysicalMediaType;
    public uint LinkSpeed;
    public ulong PacketsSent;
    public ulong PacketsReceived;
    public uint InitTime;
    public uint ConnectTime;
    public ulong BytesSent;
    public ulong BytesReceived;
    public ulong DirectedBytesReceived;
    public ulong DirectedPacketsReceived;
    public uint PacketsReceiveErrors;
    public uint PacketsSendErrors;
    public uint ResetCount;
    public uint MediaSenseConnectCount;
    public uint MediaSenseDisconnectCount;
};

....
var myStruct = new __NIC_STAT();
myStruct.Size = (15 * 4) + (6 * 8);
var name = "PCI\\Manixx1\0";
var nameBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(name);
myStruct.ptcDeviceName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nameBytes.Length);
try
{
    Marshal.Copy(nameBytes, 0, myStruct.ptcDeviceName, nameBytes.Length);
    // make the IOCTL call, a-la
    NativeMethods.DeviceIoControl(...., ref myStruct, ....);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(myStruct.ptcDeviceName);
}
```

Comment: I think you said this backwards, "seem to think ulong is 32-bits, but it's not. It'64 bits" shouldn't it be "seem to think ulong is 64-bits, but it's not. It's 32 bits." Since you were referring to the native struct, not the managed one.

Comment: I clarified.  The OP had defined the C# struct using `ulong` assuming that they are 32-bit, which they aren't.

Comment: @ctacke MSDN says that `UnmanagedType.LPWStr` is supported on compact framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172512.aspx

Comment: @ctacke

Sir Can you please suggest me for this

[Marshalling C Struct with array of structures in it *C#.Net CF for WIN CE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964241/marshalling-c-struct-with-array-of-structures-in-it-c-net-cf-for-win-ce)

Comment: @ctacke

Hi Sir
[Can we Implement Mouse Click Event in c# .net compact framework WINCE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125727/can-we-implement-mouse-click-event-in-c-sharp-net-compact-framework-wince)