# Marshal.SizeOf() & Marshal.StructureToPtr() Throwing Exceptions in .NET CF WIN-CE

Tags: c#, .net, windows-ce

I am working on C#.Net CF for WIN-CE platform. In my code I am using

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(struct_Obj));

IntPtr newptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_Obj, newptr, false);
```

I am trying to send this struct info:

```
     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct __NIC_STAT
{

    ulong Size;               //  Of this structure.

    public Char[] ptcDeviceName;      //  The device name to be queried.. 

    ulong DeviceState;        //  DEVICE_STATE_XXX above
    ulong DeviceState;        //  DEVICE_STATE_XXX above
    ulong MediaType;          //  NdisMediumXXX
    ulong MediaState;         //  MEDIA_STATE_XXX above
    ulong PhysicalMediaType;
    ulong LinkSpeed;          //  In 100bits/s. 10Mb/s = 100000
    UInt64 PacketsSent;
    UInt64 PacketsReceived;
    ulong InitTime;           //  In milliseconds
    ulong ConnectTime;        //  In seconds
    UInt64 BytesSent;          //  0 - Unknown (or not supported)
    UInt64 BytesReceived;      //  0 - Unknown (or not supported)
    UInt64 DirectedBytesReceived;
    UInt64 DirectedPacketsReceived;
    ulong PacketsReceiveErrors;
    ulong PacketsSendErrors;
    ulong ResetCount;
    ulong MediaSenseConnectCount;
    ulong MediaSenseDisconnectCount; 

} ;
```

when I run the code in WIN-CE machine, I am getting "not supported exception".Those two methods are throwing exceptions.

Can anybody tell me how to find the structure size and how to convert structure to Ptr with out any issues for WIN-CE.

Thanks!!

Comment: According to the docs they are supported. What does `struct_Obj` look like?

Comment: struct_obj is the object for PNIC_STATISTICS structure in nuiouser.h

Comment: Yes. But what does your translation look like?

Comment: I need to convert the structure to a pointer and have to send the pointer to DEviceIO control API

please check my Qn here [DeviceIoControl (IOCTL_NDISUIO_NIC_STATISTICS) is failed in WINCE7 C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479009/deviceiocontrol-ioctl-ndisuio-nic-statistics-is-failed-in-wince7-c-net)

Comment: yes, we can modify the prototype, but it should match with the corresponding IOCTL in the Win CE driver.. 

so I need to send the structure pointer to the DeviceIoControl.

Comment: What I am proposing does exactly that

Comment: yup I modified the Declaration to support for structure objects but getting exception: Not supported exception and last error code 87 in winCE machine

Comment: I cannot comment with seeing the code. Show an SSCCE please/.

Comment: It has the example both in C++ and C# (my code)

[Read_Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479009/deviceiocontrol-ioctl-ndisuio-nic-statistics-is-failed-in-wince7-c-net)

Comment: That is not an SSCCE. It has partial code. And it's at a different place. Code should stand alone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50032/discussion-between-arya2arya-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: You're trying to hard to have the marshaler do whatcan be done by hand. The size is simple, just manually calculate it since it's not going to be changing.  (15 * 4) + (6 * 8)

Comment: And why the shenanigans on `StructToPtr`?  Just pass it to the API as a `ref __NIC_STAT` and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct is declared incorrectly. The C++ `ULONG` is a 32 bit unsigned type. But in C#, `ulong` is 64 bits. That's clearly a huge problem.

On top of that, I must admit to being slightly sceptical about using `char[]` in the way you do. I would do it as a string with `UnmanagedType.LPWStr`.

So I would have your struct like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct __NIC_STAT
{
    uint Size;   
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]        
    public string ptcDeviceName; 
    uint DeviceState;      
    uint DeviceState;      
    uint MediaType;        
    uint MediaState;       
    uint PhysicalMediaType;
    uint LinkSpeed;        
    ulong PacketsSent;
    ulong PacketsReceived;
    uint InitTime;      
    uint ConnectTime;   
    ulong BytesSent;    
    ulong BytesReceived; 
    ulong DirectedBytesReceived;
    ulong DirectedPacketsReceived;
    uint PacketsReceiveErrors;
    uint PacketsSendErrors;
    uint ResetCount;
    uint MediaSenseConnectCount;
    uint MediaSenseDisconnectCount; 
};
```

I'm not sure why `Marshal.SizeOf` is failing for you. You may need to declare `ptcDeviceName` as `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni` to set the value. That at least makes the struct blittable and if `Marshal.SizeOf` still fails then you can fall back on `sizeof`.

Comment: Sir, Whether WIN CE Platform will support these APIs??

Marshal.SizeOf() & Marshal.StructureToPtr() 

I am trying to calculate the struct size & converting to Pointer.

any other way of sending the struct info to DeviceIoControl?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm not a user of WinCE so I only know what I can read in the docs.

Comment: Yeah, the CF isn't going to like that MarshalAs.

Comment: @David: yep.  No other option (well it could be done unsafe with a pointer, or a uint, but you understand).

Comment: `StringToHGlobalUni` is also unsupported in the CF.  I posted a solution in the duplicate of this question (before I realized you had answered over here)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan can you please clarify my doubt

[Conversion of C/C++ Struct To C#.Net CF WinCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560958/conversion-of-c-c-struct-to-c-net-cf-wince)

Comment: @ctacke According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172512.aspx `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)` is supported

Comment: Certainly an interesting article.  Sometimes MSDN is wrong, and sometimes I am (not sure who has a better track record).  If it is supported, I've never used it.  Now that may well be because I've been doing CF work since pre 1.0 and I just got used to the marshaler sucking ass and having to do everything by hand, and therefor continued doing it manually even after they added some features (this would likely be a 3.5 addition because I know if didn't work in 2.0 when I spent a month doing WZC work that would have used this).  It would certainly be worth the OP's time to test this possibility.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan

[Sir Can you please suggest me for this Marshalling C Struct with array of structures in it *C#.Net CF for WIN CE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964241/marshalling-c-struct-with-array-of-structures-in-it-c-net-cf-for-win-ce)