# Conversion of C/C++ Struct To C#.Net CF WinCE

Tags: c#, c++, .net, struct, compact-framework

Hi I am trying to convert the C/C++ Strcut to C#

C/C++ Struct looks like:

```
         typedef struct _NDISUIO_QUERY_OID
         {
           NDIS_OID        Oid;
           PTCHAR          ptcDeviceName;  
           UCHAR           Data[sizeof(ULONG)];
         } NDISUIO_QUERY_OID, *PNDISUIO_QUERY_OID;
```

My C# Struct is:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

    public struct _NDISUIO_QUERY_OID
    {
        public uint        Oid;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string          ptcDeviceName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8*sizeof(uint))]
        public string Data;
    };
```

I was bit doubtful about the converted structure, can anyone clarify me about this conversion??

If possible can anyone please tell me any tutorials or some references that are useful for conversion of data types or structures from c/c++ to C#.Net CF.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [previous question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22479009), @ctacke said that you won't be able to use `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)` with the compact framework. He asserted that you would have to declare that field as `IntPtr`, and marshal it manually.

However, this [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172512.aspx) states that `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)` works under the compact framework. I suppose I am inclined to believe the MSDN documents.

The final member is also declared incorrectly. The `SizeConst` must be `sizeof(uint)`.

Comment: Sir Thanks :)

MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr) is also supporting :)

I have to verify the last parameter, I am Bit doubtful about it !!

Comment: Definitely let us know if it works with MarshalAs for both of those fields.

Comment: @ctacke 

Yes sir it's working.. no exceptions..

MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr) is supporting in WIN CE.

Comment: @ctacke Sir 
Can you please give me a suggestion..

[How to do memcpy in C# .Net CF with the following task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604111/how-to-do-memcpy-in-c-sharp-net-cf-with-the-following-task)