# Marshalling C Struct with array of structures in it

Tags: c#, compact-framework, pinvoke, windows-embedded-compact

I referred the similar questions in this forum but didn't get the solution for my problem.

I have been struggling with marshaling problem for a while. I have a structure that contains an array of another structure, The platform is **Win CE**. I am using Visual Studio 2008 and .NET CF 3.5.

**The code:**

**C Structures:**

```
 struct dot11Rate
 {
    unsigned int rate;
    unsigned char mode; 
 };

 typedef struct my_supported_rates
 {
    unsigned short n_rates;
    struct dot11Rate srates[36];
    unsigned char  isSet;
    unsigned char no_of_HTStreams;
 }MY_SUPPORTED_DATA_RATES;
```

Size of the struct MY_SUPPORTED_DATA_RATES is **296 bytes** in **C**

**This is my attempt to convert it into a C# struct:**

**C# Converted:**

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct dot11Rate
    {
        public uint rate;
        public byte mode; /* HT=1, non-HT=0*////
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct my_supported_rates
    {       
        public ushort n_rates;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst = 36)]
        public dot11Rate[] srates;
        public byte isSet;
        public byte no_of_HTStreams;
    };
```

Here I am getting the size as **304 bytes** using `Marshal.SizeOf(my_supported_rates);`

I have tried the following things without any success:

- Adding and removing various attrubute elements in MarshalAs attribute in my_supported_rates struct such as `ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct`
- I have Intptr with required data and I tried to convert ptr to the struct using the code `my_supported_rates = (my_supported_rates)
  Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr,my_supported_rates.GetType());`. But proper conversion is not happend.
- Some other suggestions on blogs and StackOverflow which didn't prove
  useful to me

Comment: I don't have CE, but your C# struct has SizeOf 296 in my desktop C# program. Btw, you should remove `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` since there is no text data in your structs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan

Thanks!! I removed `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode`

Remaining struct marshalling has no problems isn't it?

Comment: It looks fine to me as I said. I don't understand where 304 comes from. That's on CE right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan

yes sir in WIN CE machine I am getting `Marshal.SizeOf(my_supported_rates);` **304 Bytes**

Comment: You mean Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(...))?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan

Yes Sir..!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan

Hi Sir
[Can we Implement Mouse Click Event in c# .net compact framework WINCE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125727/can-we-implement-mouse-click-event-in-c-sharp-net-compact-framework-wince)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translations look good to me. Running on desktop rather than CE I find that, for these types

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct dot11Rate
{
    public uint rate;
    public byte mode;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct my_supported_rates
{       
    public ushort n_rates;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst = 36)]
    public dot11Rate[] srates;
    public byte isSet;
    public byte no_of_HTStreams;
};
```

that

```
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(my_supported_rates)) == 296
```

So it would seem to be something odd in the CE pinvoke marshaller. You might need to force the hand of the marshaller by doing this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=296)]
public struct my_supported_rates
{       
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ushort n_rates;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst = 36)]
    public dot11Rate[] srates;
    [FieldOffset(292)]
    public byte isSet;
    [FieldOffset(293)]
    public byte no_of_HTStreams;
};
```

That is, if `LayoutKind.Explicit` and `FieldOffset` are supported on CE.

If they are not supported then you'll need to marshal by hand. You are looking for `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` and then `Marshal.ReadByte`, `Marshal.ReadInt16` and so on.