# Getting Mouse Events on a ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, windows-embedded-compact

I am working on WINCE platform, developing windows form app in C#, I need to implement a mouse click event for **DROP DOWN BOX**, but compact framework doesn't have a support for mouse click events.

Can anyone suggest me any alternative way to implement the MOUSE CLICK EVENT for combobox (DROP DOWN BOX).?

PS: I am using GOT FOCUS EVENT on drop down box but it's not flexible, I need to run the code when the DROP DOWN BOX is clicked or when it is DROPPED DOWN.

Any suggestions or code snippets will Help me a lot. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I will happy if this could help u,otherwise please do not vote down :D ;)

u can use this event on your form:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int maxX = 1000;
        int minX = 5;
        int maxY = 1000;
        int minY = 5;

            if ((MousePosition.X < maxX) && (MousePosition.X > minX)
                 && (MousePosition.Y > minY) && (MousePosition.Y < maxY))
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
```

As u can see I have limited the position of mouse. this must work ;)

Comment: i find something . wait until I Format them into codes

Comment: here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa451226.aspx) is msdn link that let u can gain idea

Comment: I have added working code now. test that but notice u must get minX,maxX,minY,maxY from your DROP DOWN BOX properties